# ASP.Net Core 2.1 OData Parameter issue

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to get OData to work in ASP.Net 2.1.  The main Get is ok as I get the results from the DB.

When I try to call the second Get with a Parameter it returns with a 404. I put a breakpoint on the second get and it never hits. The http "get" statement http://localhost:5000/odata/userrole('Admin')

```
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/odata/userrole('Admin')
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 423.7117ms 404
```

What am I not doing right here?  Thank you.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Odata = v7.1.0

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class UserRoleController : ODataController
    {

        private IMyDB _db;

        public UserRoleController(IMyDB db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 20)]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_db.UserRole().AsQueryable());
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get([FromODataUri] string roletype)
        {
            return Ok(_db.UserRole().Find(roletype));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what is the problem.   In the future if someone is working with OData this might help in countless hours of debugging.

The UserRole Class  I have looks like below.  **Notice** the data annotation [Key], that is what is causing the OData to ignore the path.   I need to change the data Type to match the UserRole class "key"  `public IActionResult Get([FromODataUri] Guid roleid)`
That fixes the problem.  Hope this helps people in the future.

```
public class UserRole
{
   [Key]
   public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
   public Role RoleType { get; set; }
   public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```